# node js callback ambiguity

Tags: node.js, redis

I am trying to use redis with nodejs.

This code is working fine :

---

```
express = require('express'); 
app = express();
logger = require('express-logger');
app.use(logger({path: "/home/debanjan/Documents/nodejs/project1/logfile.txt"}));

var redis = require('redis'); 
var client = redis.createClient();
client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

app.get(function(req,res,next){
console.log("Date " + Date.now() + " :: Time " + Time.now());
next();
})

app.get('/api/:name',function(req,res){
res.status(200);
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
client.get(req.params.name , function(err,data){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error encountered!");
        }else{  
            console.log("Value fetched ..." + data);
            res.jsonp({"result": data});    
            res.send();
        }
    }); 
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("Ready to launch...");
});
```

---

However , this is not .

---

```
express = require('express');
app = express();
logger = require('express-logger');
app.use(logger({path: "/home/debanjan/Documents/nodejs/project1/logfile.txt"}));

var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

app.get(function(req,res,next){
    console.log("Date " + Date.now() + " :: Time " + Time.now());
    next();
})

app.get('/api/:name',function(req,res){
res.status(200);
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
fetchFromDb(req.params.name,res);   
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Ready to launch...");
});

function fetchFromDb(name,res){
   console.log("Key given : [" + name+"]");
   value = new Object;
   client.get(name,function(err,data){
      if(err)
         console.log("Error encountered!");
      console.log("Value fetched ..." + data);
   });  

   res.jsonp({"result": value});
   res.send();
}
```

---

When I am doing a curl:
     curl -i   [localhost] :3000/api/Kendra_Loud
the 1st instance returns proper data,however,the second one returns null. Why is moving the code that is doing the work to a different function causing the issue ? also "res" seems to be out of scope when accessed inside the client.get in 2nd part,however in the 1st part it isn't so. 
Can anyone please explain what I am missing here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your 2nd example returns `null` and the correct set of data, and you've shown the code as is? Do you see that you never change the value of `value` variable (after assigning an empty object to it), yet send it in your response?

Comment: And yes, the problem is not of scope, but of time: `res.jsonp()` will be invoked _before_ `client.get` has finished its job.

Answer (score 0):

You're not waiting for the asynchronous `client.get()` to finish before sending your response. Change your `fetchFromDb()` function to something like this:

```
function fetchFromDb(name,res){
   console.log("Key given : [" + name+"]");
   client.get(name,function(err,data){
      if(err)
         console.log("Error encountered!");
      console.log("Value fetched ..." + data);
      res.jsonp({"result": data});
   });
}
```

Also, you should avoid creating globals by prefixing your variable declarations with `var`.

Comment: Well, do you see `Error encountered!` in your console?